# Active connections number reached maximum Mongo Atlas

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-core

I have an .NetCore application. My DB is Mongo and hosted on Mongo Atlas. I reach the number of maximum connections very easy. I have a lot of request made to the db but my connection with the DB is Singletone.

[image]

I connect to Mongo through Mongo Client

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(config.GetConnectionString("Dbconnectionstring"));
IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase("database");
```

All this in a class that is registered as a singletone in Startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<MongoUnitOfWork>();
```

I did not have this problem before. On this current application I have to make a lot of requests to the db but if I registered the connection as I singleton I expected to use the same connection and not open a new one for every request. At least this is what I think it happens.

**UPDATE**

I used a recurrent service named HangFire (intended to use for recurring jobs) that needed a connection string to the DB. Even though I didn't put any function to be automatically called every 1 minute or something similar, I think this was the problem. For now I commented every thing about this service and everything went back to normal.

I will get back as soon as I'm 100% sure that this was the problem.

**UPDATE 2**

Today I had the problem again so I figured that the Recurrent Service wasn't the problem.

**UPDATE 3**

Last time when I got rid of that service I also deleted all the connections. Until now I didn't have another problem and when I checked them in the day that I deleted the service all seemed fine. Today I checked again the connections and I had around 70. Apparently the connections don't close.

Also, yes, I'm sure I'm using a singleton to instantiate the MongoClient. I also put breakpoints to see if the they are hit on request. Not the requests are the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you are _really_ creating a Singleton? Are you sure your application only runs once?

Comment: Share a small sample of code that replicates the problem. Note that the `MongoClient` instance returned need only be connected **once** per application lifecycle. If you have code which is calling the same block to re-instantiate that instance on each call, then your code is doing the wrong thing. But any question presenting such a problem needs reproducible code.

Comment: Yes I'm sure it's a Singleton. I showed you what I register in the Startup.cs. That MongoUnitOfWork class is where I instantiate MongoClient.